# Freud's tripartite linguistic play

Tags: philosophy-of-language, psychoanalysis, freud

Maria Walsh in her book Art and Psychoanalysis says:

> Uncanny sensations are triggered in the present by the creepy
>   evocation of a past that the subject has repressed, a past that should
>   have been over and done with, but which comes back to haunt the
>   subject, making time and space seem out of joint. The ambivalent
>   nature of the uncanny can be seen in the tripartite linguistic play
>   that Freud delineates in his essay.

Does anyone have any information about Freud's tripartite linguistic play? I did not find anything about it on the web.

Comment: Have you read Freud’s essay she speaks of?  It could mean that Freud makes a play on certain German words. If she means this, then she should be more clear. I rather doubt anyone here has read this book. I could be wrong, but you may have more luck on another forum.

Comment: You may also be able to find a review of her book in an academic journal. If you luck up and find a good reviewer you can learn a lot about the book in question. (In other words this may be more about Walsh and her interpretation than it is about Freud. I simply don’t know.)

Answer (score 2):

The essay is online, there is a [wikipedia article (Uncanny)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny), Walsh's book [p.21](https://books.google.bg/books?id=p5sMKTqE44MC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Maria+Walsh++Art+and+Psychoanalysis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0yqDTsc7lAhXVxcQBHb0iBkAQ6AEIJzAA#v=snippet&q=linguistic&f=false) can be seen on googlebooks. Heimliche is the original German word which, as it is explained by Freud and his commentators, has a meaning that comes actually very close to its inverse, that is unheimliche, So the word has 2 meanings and there is a separate word unheimliche which is the 3rd element. At least this appears to be M. Walsh' count.